# NORMDIST in Google Sheets gives me an exponential distribution

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, normal-distribution

When trying to plot values in Google Sheets to create a normal distribution, I end up with an exponential function. The values I am using are,

Average: 3241.822222
Std Dev: 356.3838934

Choosing other values causes the distribution to correct itself to the expected bell curve.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Here is a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5I__uiKaI5gLsZuqRgzoumZuJ93fSycVodluOGh4ac/edit#gid=0) with this example.

Comment: Why do you have only 100 bins?  Shouldn't the max bins be around 6000 (wherever the end of the distribution should be?

Comment: Doh! You're right. I was using another example to mimic and didn't realize that only has values from 0-100 which is why I chose my bins in that way.